# How to insert multiple records from JSON API call to SQL Server table

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, sql-server, rest

The code below is from an api I am setting up(first time) and I am having an issue with this setup accepting an array of JSON coming into the endpoint. I am using Postman for testing. For several endpoint I would want to be able to accept an array of data to be inserted to the DB, etc, but I am unsure how to get to that point.

When I try to do something like below in the post body:

```
     [
        {
            "proofID": 999,
            "client": "someJob999",
            "runSeq": 1000,
            "result": null
        },
        {
            "proofID": 1000,
            "client": "someJob1000",
            "runSeq": 10001,
            "result": null
        }
    ]
```

I am returned the auto incremented id of a single inserted row with null values like below:

```
[
    [
        {
            "ID": 61,
            "proofID": null,
            "client": null,
            "runSeq": null,
            "result": null
        }
    ]
]
```

All code below relates to building the api.

````
//////////JobData_dbconfig.js//////////
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
require('dotenv').config();

const configJobData = {
    user: process.env.SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.SQL_PASS,
    server: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    database: process.env.SQL_DB1,
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAort: true,
    },
    port: process.env.SQL_PORT1
}

module.exports = configJobData;


//////////classes.js/////////////
            class proofs{
                constructor(ID,proofID,runSeq,client,result){
                    this.ID = ID;
                    this.proofID = proofID;
                    this.runSeq = runSeq;
                    this.client = client;
                    this.result = result;
                }
            }  
            
            module.exports = {
                proofs: proofs
            };
    
//////////SQL Stored Procedure/////////
    USE [JobData2]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insertProof]    Script Date: 7/9/2021 10:38:41 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertProof] @proofID int, @runSeq int, @client varchar(75), @result varchar(15)
    AS
    INSERT INTO JobData2.dbo.Proofs (proofID,runSeq,client,result)
    OUTPUT Inserted.[ID], Inserted.[proofID], Inserted.[client], Inserted.[runSeq], Inserted.[result]
    VALUES (@proofID,@runSeq,@client,@result)
    
    
            
//////////dboperations.js////////////
                require('dotenv').config()
                
                var configJobData = require('./JobData_dbconfig');
                const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
                    
                async function addProof(proof){
                    try{
                        let pool = await sql.connect(configJobData);
                        let insertProof = await pool.request()
                            .input('proofID', sql.Int, proof.proofID)
                            .input('runSeq', sql.Int, proof.runSeq)
                            .input('client', sql.VarChar, proof.client)
                            .input('result', sql.VarChar, proof.result)
                            .execute('insertProof');
                
                        return insertProof.recordsets;
                    }
                    catch (error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
                
                module.exports = {
                    addProof: addProof
                }
        
///////////application////////////
            require('dotenv').config()
            
            const express = require('express')
            var cors = require('cors')
            const app = express()
            
            
            //rate limiter
            const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')
            const limiter = rateLimit({
                windowMs: process.env.svrLimit, //30 min
                max: process.env.svrMax, //limit each IP to 100 requests per 30min
                message: "Too many requests from this IP in the last 30 min, please try again later."
            })
           
            
            //db 
            const dboperations = require('./dboperations')
            var configJobData = require('./JobData_dbconfig')
            var configEliteMaster = require('./EliteMaster_dbconfig')
            const dbclasses = require('./models/db/classes')
            
            //app
            app.use(express.json())
            app.use(cors())
            
            //app post endpoint
            app.post('/api/proofs', limiter, (req,res) => {
                let proof = { ...req.body }
                dboperations.addProof(proof).then(result => {
                    //console.log(result);
                    res.status(201).json(result);
                })
            })
            
            
            var port = process.env.PORT || 8090
            app.listen(port)
            console.log('server is running at port ' + port)
     ```
````

Comment: I believe the issue may lie in my SQL Stored Procedure but am unsure how to modify it to be dynamic and accept as few as 1 or as many as are provided in the JSON payload to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back to this and solved it today by doing the following:

1. Modified my sql stored procedure to be as below:

```
        USE [JobData2]
    GO
    
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[addProofs]    Script Date: 7/20/2021 4:53:55 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addProofs] @proofs nvarchar(max)
    AS
    DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = @proofs
    INSERT INTO JobData2.dbo.Proofs (proofID, runSeq, client, result)
    OUTPUT Inserted.[ID], Inserted.[proofID], Inserted.[runSeq], Inserted.[client], Inserted.[result]
     SELECT * 
     FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (proofID int, runSeq int, client varchar(75), result varchar(15))
    GO
```

2. Modified my dboperation function to be:

```
async function addProof(proof){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(configJobData);
        let insertProof = await pool.request()
            .input('proofs', sql.NVarChar, proof)
            .execute('addProofs');

        return insertProof.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

3. Modified my endpoint to be setup as below:

```
router.post('/', publimiter, authenticateToken, (req,res) => {
    let proof = JSON.stringify(req.body)
            dboperations.addProof(proof).then(result => {
            //console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json(result);
    })
})
```

Essentially, this is setting up "proof" to contain the entire request body when the endpoint is hit, which is then passed to the stored procedure as "proofs" via the dboperations as a param, and then using OPENJSON in the stored proc, inserts each object set in the array to the DB and returns the inserted data back to the user.

Anyhow, this may be common to seasoned devs but I hope it helps out some other newbie like me!